# How to render a blazor component in an iframe

Tags: c#, iframe, rendering, blazor-server-side, blazor-component

Is it possible to render a **Blazor component** in an `iframe`?

The component which I want to render resides into another project. The idea is to exclude that other project if not required for the build. But since the component which I am using is from that other project, if I exclude that project, it will give reference error.

I came accross `iframe` while doing RnD on this. In `iframe` we specify `src` which is the page we want to render. In this case, how do I specify a **blazor** component? I tried specifying `Component.razor`, `http://localhost:1234/Component.razor` etc. but the frame appears blank as shown below.
[image]